# How do I draw an Image into a panel?

Tags: c#, image, panel, paint, paintevent

I've been trying to fix this issue for hours but whenever I try to draw my image into my panel, it doesn't appear at all. My panel does have a paint event that with the image being "drawn" inside the method. The panel I am trying to draw into does have a background image. I'm not sure if that is interfering with anything. As well as that, the panel is nested in a usercontrol that is nested in a form. One of my questions is, if I do

```
private void Panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{ 
    img = Properties.Resources.Image;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(0,0));
}
```

where is it being drawn exactly? to the form? or to the panel?

At first, I tried picture box and I've learned that making the image transparent makes it so that it gets the color of the back color. Confusing part is that I drew that same picture box inside the panel yet it grabbed the color of the form instead. I have not tested out changing the back color of the panel and it probably was just grabbing the same color.

Comment: DO NOT access `Properties.Resources` like that. Every time you do that, new data is extracted from the assembly and a new `Image` object created. That means that your code would be creating multiple objects and never disposing any of them. Access `Properties.Resources.Image` once and once only. Assign the result to a field and then use that field in your event handler, so you keep drawing the same `Image` object.

Comment: *"The panel I am trying to draw into does have a background image. I'm not sure if that is interfering with anything"*. Why are you telling us this? Why haven't you already checked that for yourself? Remove the background image and see if that fixes the issue. That's problem-solving 101. Don;t ask us to do something that you can easily do for yourself. Do all that you can BEFORE posting the question at all.

Comment: Speaking of problem-solving 101, another thing that you should have already done is create a new test project and isolated the problem functionality. Create a new project with nothing but a `Panel` and a `Paint` event handler. You could even remove the resource part to make sure that's not the problem. If that test project draws the `Image` as expected then you know that things actually work exactly as you expect and you have somehow broken something in the real project. You can start looking for differences and/or reimplement the functionality in the real project.

Comment: Have you confirmed that that code is even being executed? It wouldn't be the first time an event handler has not been connected to an event. You can put a breakpoint on that method and check whether it's hit when you run the project. If it's not then that's obviously the issue. There's no point trying to fix code that isn't even being executed. Again, debugging the code like this is something you need to do before posting a question and specify that you have done so when you post.

Comment: @jmcilhinney my image was being drawn behind a picture box thus I wasn’t able to see. I assumed when I ran the drawimage method, it would draw on top but I guess it didn’t. Now I’m wondering if I can draw images on top of picture boxes.

Comment: You can draw on pretty much any control, because `Paint` is a member of the `Control` class, although some controls do have some limitations. As for your issue, think about how things work in the real world. If you had a wall with a picture frame hanging on it and you drew on the wall, would you be able to see that drawing? Of course not, because it would be covered by the picture frame. That's exactly how your `Panel` and `PictureBox` were behaving. Controls have a z-order and are designed to behave like real-world objects that way.

Comment: This raises the question though, why are you using GDI+ drawing at all instead of simply setting the `Image` property of the `PictureBox`? Drawing like this can be easily changed and erased so, if that's what you want to do, doing it this way makes sense. If you just want to display a picture though, that's what a `PictureBox` is for.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the reason why I want to draw it as an image is due to the fact that the transparent function of a picture box will result in getting the back color and that is not what I’m going for.

Comment: What you said makes little sense and what you think you said probably isn't really true, but I'm not really sure. It would behove you to get a clear understanding of what you're talking about, which would require you to be able to explain it clearly, but these comments are not really the place to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `System.Windows.Forms.Panel`, then the image will be drawn exactly in the panel starting from the top left corner. No additional configuration required (exact `Paint` event subscriptions). The image will be drawn at 100% scale, so if the image will be larger than the panel, then you will only see the part of the image.

So, check the following:

- `img` contains the image of the appropriate size
- there are no transparent parts in the image (to avoid the case where you see only a part of the image and that part is transparent).
- make sure that the panel itself is visible (add borders?)

Comment: Thank you Serg, I’ve realized that the image was being drawn behind a picture box I was using as a background.